# The application at 'android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk' does not exist or is not accessible

Tags: react-native, automation, appium

[init({"platformName":"Android","deviceName":"emulator-5554","app":"android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk"})] The environment you requested was unavailable.
    An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: The application at 'android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk' does not exist or is not accessible

Answer (score 0):

Try this in  Terminal

```
cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd ..
```